# Giving mysql database column rank

Tags: mysql, database, rank

I have a column in my database titled PositionThisWeek.

I want to assign rank to this column from the values of another column titled Points.

The rank should be from 1 upwards, how can I update the Position column?

Comment: Share the work you have done so far and what is the problem you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

One way to calculate the rank will be to use a variable, for instance:

```
select Userid, Points, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
from PointsTable, (select @rank := 0) r
order by Points desc;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a405f/1) which does the update in one way.

(Kudos to [Daniel Vassallo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function) for the idea of putting the initialisation into the select!)